# Mipmaps aren't being used

Tags: swift, shader, textures, metal, mipmaps

In Metal, I figured out how to generate and populate a `MTLTexture`'s mipmap levels. However, when I render thousands of these mipmapped textures, and zoom out, I get the distinctive shimmering. I have used Xcode's debugger to determine that these mipmap levels got populated, hence *this* code works.

```
let CommandBuffer = CommandQue.makeCommandBuffer()!, CommandEncoder =  CommandBuffer.makeBlitCommandEncoder()!
    CommandEncoder.generateMipmaps(for: BlockTextures!)
    CommandEncoder.endEncoding()
    CommandBuffer.commit()
```

The mipmap levels are created and populated, but the shimmering still occurs, meaning they aren't being rendered and *used*. How can I configure either the render pipeline or the fragment shaders, whichever one *uses* the mipmaps, how do I tell them to *use* the created mipmaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `sampler` object in your shader that sets the `mip_filter`.
For reference see 2.9 Samplers in the [metal shading language specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf).

```
constexpr sampler s(filter::linear, mip_filter::linear)
```

Alternatively, create a `MTLSamplerDescriptor`.
For more information see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/textures/improving_filtering_quality_and_sampling_performance/adding_mipmap_filtering_to_samplers?language=objc

Comment: `filter::linear` linear interpolates teh pixels, blurring them, which is not ideal for pixel art, but what's the difference between `linear` and `nearest` in `mip_filter`?

Comment: `linear` vs `nearest` in the context of `mip_filter` refer to whether sampling is done from a single (nearest) mipmap, or whether two mipmaps are sampled, and blended linearly. Linear is a bit slower and yields a slightly worse quality, but it avoids sharp changes in quality when animating, when crossing mipmap level boundaries.